# Value not persisting in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component where I am reading a file from an Upload and I need to pass the contents onto a child component for display. Now, I can successfully read the contents of the file using FileReader, and console.log shows the result of this, but the variable that I want to use in order to pass onto the child component is always null. Where am I going wrong? The code isn't anything fantastic:

```
   const Upload = props => {
     const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
     let results;
     let contentsFromFile;

   const handleFileRead = (e)=>{
      results = contentFromFile.result;
      console.log(results);
   }

   const handleSelectedFile = (e)=>{
        setFile(e.target.files[0].name)

        contentsFromFile = new FileReader();
        contentsFromFile.onloadend = handlFileRead;
        contentsFromFile.readAsText(e.target.files[0]);
  }

  return(

   /*Upload file input is here but showing this as NOT relevant to question*/

   <DisplayResults results={results} />
  );
 }
 export default Upload
```

Comment: Turn `results` into a state variable, just like `file`.

Comment: is it really null? should be undefined

Comment: I tried adding results to useState, but render threw an error

Answer (score 0):

Because I am using React Hooks, I just needed to set another const with useState(null) to save the value to a state as shown when setting the file.